# Filtering features in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

When I was using Openlayers 2 I could compose various filters like `OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO` or `OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE` and then use a WFS protocol and a callback function to get features according to user input and those native WFS filters.

In Openlayers 3 [WFS](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.format.WFS.html), I dont see those native filters.

So, now, how do I get features according to user input? I get the input and make an old-fashioned query to the PostGIS? I reset the `ol.Vector` source `url`?

Please provide some help, or some tutorials

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `url` in OpenLayers 3 to use the OGC FE (Filter Encoding) syntax.
In fact, `OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO` or `OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE` were building for you this filter string behind the scene.

If you look at [the OpenLayers official WFS demo](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/vector-wfs.html), you see that they use `bbox` key in the URL. To do the same as `OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO`, you could replace the url with:

```
return 'http://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
        'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
        'Filter=<Filter xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><And><BBOX><PropertyName>way</PropertyName><gml:Box srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:3857"><gml:coord><gml:X>' + extent[0] + '</gml:X> <gml:Y>' + extent[1] + '</gml:Y></gml:coord><gml:coord><gml:X>' + extent[2] + '</gml:X><gml:Y>' + extent[3] + '</gml:Y></gml:coord></gml:Box></BBOX><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>landuse</PropertyName><Literal>basin</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></And></Filter>';
```

The important part is the `&filter=...` to apply Filter Encoding (FE) syntax to your WFS call.